# Changing default domain in gulp builds

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

How can I make a default build in `gulp` to be for example `site.com/test/`?

At this point it is `site.com` and I need it to be `site.com/test`.

Thanks.

EDIT: I am not allowed to put gulp configuration, can you guys give me an example of how it can be done please? Sorry for this question.. I hate it more than you do.

Comment: What is your gulp configuration ?

Comment: gulp configuration is never the same, so without it we cannot help you very much.

Comment: Editing @Weedoze

Comment: I have edited my question, sorry..

Comment: @JohnSam it is complicated to help you without the config. If you cannot provide it due to confidentiality you can edit the sensible part with random names for example